# Python: subprocess and running a bash script with multiple arguments

Tags: python, bash, arguments, subprocess, popen

How do I go about running a bash script using the subprocess module, to which I must give several arguments?

This is what I'm currently using:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/my/file/path/programname.sh', 'arg1 arg2 %s' % arg3], \
    shell = True)
```

The bash script seems not to be taking any of the parameters in. Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Pass arguments as a list, see [the very first code example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['/my/file/path/programname.sh', 'arg1', 'arg2', arg3])
```

If `arg3` is not a string; convert it to string before passing to `check_call()`: `arg3 = str(arg3)`.

Comment: If all of my args are variables, do I not set them as strings?

Comment: @user2510173: I don't understand the question. Here's an example: `arg3 = 1`, to convert it, you could call `str(arg3)` that returns `'1'`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example in the code does not answer the original question, since they chose a too-simple case of just a single argument.  It is unclear whether multiple arguments should be passed as a single string, or as multiple ones, unless you read well down the page to the details behind POpen.  Even then, it only says, "Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred" - not, "you must supply multiple arguments as a list"

Comment: @SteveBroberg: do you mean the example in the official Python documentation? You can report it as a documentation bug at https://bugs.python.org ([patches are welcome](https://docs.python.org/devguide/docquality.html) but a simple report that points out a possible issue could be also useful).

Answer (score 15):

```
subprocess.Popen(['/my/file/path/programname.sh arg1 arg2 %s' % arg3], shell = True).
```

If you use `shell = True` the script and its arguments have to be passed as a string. Any other elements in the `args` sequence will be treated as arguments to the shell.

You can find the complete docs at http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.

Answer (score 3):

One more example, which is not included in all the above ones,

`subprocess.Popen(['/your/script.sh %s %s %s' %(argument1,argument2,argument3)], shell = True)`

Please note that, when you type `%(argument1,argument2,argument3)`, there should not be any space between `%` and `(`, eg `% (argument1,argument2,argument3)` is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I know that this is solution is quite late, but could help someone.

example:

```
import subprocess
pass_arg=[]
pass_arg[0]="/home/test.sh"
pass_arg[1]="arg1"
pass_arg[2]="arg2"

subprocess.check_call(pass_arg)
```

The above example provides arg1 and arg2 as parameters to the shell script test.sh

Essentially, subprocess expects an array. So you could populate an array and provide it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `args` name.

```
subprocess.Popen(args=['./test.sh', 'arg1 arg2 %s' % arg3], shell=True)
```

Comment: so the file path needs to be in the args set as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["path/to/file.sh", arg1, arg2, arg3])
```