# Python: run a bash script with standard input from python

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script file called g2p which runs as following:

```
$echo "teststring" | ./g2p @g2pumap=./map.txt
```

Now I am writing a python script using python 2.6, I need to run this bash script( g2p) inside python.

I checked this answer:[Python: subprocess and running a bash script with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242828/python-subprocess-and-running-a-bash-script-with-multiple-arguments?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I wrote:

```
import subprocess

val = subprocess.check_call(["./eng_GBR/g2p",  "./map.txt"],  shell=True)
```

my problem is how to send standard input to g2p (bash script) inside python code, and also I get a bit confused about pass value to @g2pumap argument.

Answer (score 2):

*The restriction to Python2.6 was added to the question later on. A portable solution is at the end of this answer.*

---

Since Python 3.5, [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) should match most "call program with X" use cases. It's `input` parameter does what you want:

> The `input` argument is passed to [...] the subprocess’s stdin.

You can feed it a *bytes* string directly:

```
import subprocess

g2p_process = subprocess.run(["./eng_GBR/g2p",  "@g2pumap=./map.txt"], input=b'teststring\n')
```

This is equivalent to your bash call. Note that you must add appropriate newlines (`b"\n"` at the end) by yourself. Any arguments, such as `@g2pumap=./map.txt`, can be passed in without escaping.

If you want to have the Exception of `check_call`, use `g2p_process.check_returncode()` afterwards.

---

If you are stuck with an older version or need backwards compatibility, using a bare `subprocess.Popen` is the most portable. The following should handle your use case:

```
import subprocess

g2p_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["./eng_GBR/g2p", "@g2pumap=./map.txt"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  # allow sending data via STDIN
)
g2p_process.communicate(input="teststring\n")
if g2p_process.returncode != 0:
    raise RuntimeError
```

Note that you can also capture stdout and stderr if you need to. Use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and/or `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` in the call to `Popen`. Doing so lets `g2p_process.communicate` return a meaningful tuple of `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`.

See the `subprocess.Popen` [method docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) on how to work with such an object. It is usually a good idea to check its `returncode`, or `kill` dangling processes. You can also replicate [`subprocess.run`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/subprocess.py#L453) if you feel like it, since it does proper error handling.

Comment: Sinec I am using python 2.6.6 , it does not have this attribute, I think I should use "subprocess.call/check_call""

Comment: You should point out that version restriction in your question. Python 2.6.6 is *seriously* outdated.

Comment: I think Python 2.6 is halfway *ancient*. People only use 2.7 and 3.x nowadays.

Comment: People with a *choice* use 2.7 or 3.x. But yes, 2.6 is old enough to warrant special mention.

Comment: @Zeinab I have added a version that works with Python 2.4 - 3.X.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

value1=...
value2=...
......

val = subprocess.check_call(["path/script.sh",  value1+" "+value2+" "+ .... ],  shell=True)
```