# How do I pass an input to an .sh file with python and subprocess?

Tags: python, shell, input, subprocess

In my current project I'm trying to execute a .sh file with a python program, giving input and reading output
The problem is that I have no idea on how to give the input (I managed to read the output in this way, searching on the internet. I'll listen to any suggestion). Here I write an example code (for the original one is longer and more complicated, but this is the essence and the problem is the same)

```
import subprocess
greet = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "helloWorld.sh"],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         encoding="utf-8")
print(greet.stdout.read())
```

and this is the simple helloWorld.sh

```
read name
echo "Hello $name"
```

My OS is Debian (xfce) and I'm wirting in Python 3.7
Ask  for any other detail

Comment: Did you try `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` as another argument to `Popen`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242828/python-subprocess-and-running-a-bash-script-with-multiple-arguments this may help you

Comment: I tried but I don't really know how to use it. Could you write an example?
@GordonAitchJay

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, that's showing command-line arguments, not stdin content. Different thing.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Yes, tried them all (and could't make them work)

Comment: BTW, ideally you should add a shebang to your `helloWorld` script, take off the `.sh` extension, set the executable permission bit, and just run it with `["./helloWorld"]`. `.sh` extensions imply compatibility with `/bin/sh`, which is a different shell from bash, but in present circumstances there's no reason not to let your script select its own interpreter rather than require its caller to use the right one.

Comment: Anyhow, see the linked duplicate -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument -- it's directly on-point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did't find the answer there, but I found out testing that modifying the .sh file (I have yet to do the things you suggested me in the previous comment) to """echo "Hello $1""" and the line in the .py one to """greet = subprocess.Popen(args=["bash", "helloWorld.sh", "name"],""" the output works  just fine.

Comment: Right, that's the command-line-argument approach, as given in the answer Chetan linked early on. Better practice, but also not what you asked for.